# Redirecting output of cat to sort

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, pipe

I have the following problem:
Names of cities should be accepted from the keyboard. This list of cities should be combined
with the list of cities present in the file cityfile. This combined list should be sorted and the sorted output should be stored in a file newfile.
I have to solve it using pipelining. I wrote following pipelines:

```
cat >>  cityfile | sort > newfile

sort | cat >> cityfile >  newfile
```

How can I pass data of cityfile to sort command ?

Comment: Your spec is ambiguous. "This list of cities should be combined with the list of cities present in the file cityfile" could mean appending the entered cities to that file or just sending both lists to the sort. You seem to be assuming the former whereas the latter makes more sense to me.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking us to do a school project for you without doing any research first.  Take a look at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ and come back if you have specific questions.

Comment: @ooga yeah I am also assuming the former.

Comment: @gareth_bowles Yes. it is school project :)

Answer (score 2):

The `cat` command concatenates input. Input can be files or *stdin*. A common key for *stdin* is "-". This also holds for the `cat` command. So you would do:

```
cat - cityfile | sort > newfile
```

You can find this information with `man cat`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you need to separate this into two steps: append the new cities to the list first, then sort.

```
cat >> filename
sort filename > newfile
```